# Is the use of 'has' appropriate with first person singular?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

We have been learning since childhood that

> *Has* can only be used with third person singular

but I have seen and heard people using *has* otherwise. For example, the other day I was reading that article in which the author wrote 'I **has** no other choice' (which according to grammar rules should be 'I have no other choice').

Is this appropriate use?

If yes, then does it indicate some kind of emphasis or Is it used to give weight to sentence?

Comment: You may wish to check out [our sister site for English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). It’s “for people who are learning or teaching English as a foreign language”, whereas here we’re more intended “for linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts”

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/20356/14666 ;0

Comment: @tchrist Not this. This is for grown ups :)

Comment: Where did you find those sentences? The source is necessary to fix the context.

Answer (score 6):

*Has* is the third person singular present tense form of the verb *have*, and in Standard English it is used for nothing else. However, other dialects may use it for other persons, and that may account for what you read.

Comment: Just to be extra clear: This means that you (HappyDev specifically here) _should not_ use ‘I has’ in English, neither written nor spoken. The form is only used in a very limited subset of dialects of English—everywhere else, it would be considered ungrammatical. Since you clearly are not a speaker of any of these dialects, you would only end up sounding like you don’t know proper English if you used it.

Comment: As well as possibly in the odd dialect, this usage went through a phase of being popular in jocular use in the UK as an imitation of the Ali G character.

Comment: It seems more of a meme-fever: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/20356/14666